# Voice over ip setup for small business

Tags: voip

I have no experience with Voip but if I wanted to use VIOP in a business with around 50 viop phones spread over 3 offices would I need to use some sort of voip Server or do most routers these days have a voip service or something built in?

Comment: Your question is a little too vague for us to really help you - you say you "want to use voip", but seem to have no idea how you want to architect the solution.  Look at the suggestions Matt gave you, and do a little research on the Googles.  If you can bring us a more focused question we can probably give you some good advice...

Comment: Actually I think the question is fine.  I understand what he's after.

Answer (score 2):

Few routers do have VOIP servers built in, but there are some.

You'll need an upstream provider to give you some SIP trunks.

Or you could just set up your own asterisk or freepbx server.
Be aware though, improper setup or securing of your VOIP server may leave you open to attack.  I believe freepbx is quite open by default, and asterisk is notorious for being hacked.

You need to firewall it properly.  Personally, I wouldn't recommend doing this if you're not familiar this type of thing.

An option you may not have considered is that there are providers out there who provide virtual VOIP PBX servers for you.  They do all the hard work and set up the phones for you.  So all you need to do is plug your VOIP phones into your network.  I used to work in this area and this is the very service we provided.  It's a very appropriate option for smaller businesses.

With regards to all of this you need a good quality internet connection with a reasonably low latency.  Although most VOIP phones have jitter buffers built in so they can cope with even delays of 100ms and still provide smooth voice service.  Bandwidth may be a consideration too.  And, QoS will become vitally important.

My recommendation is to do your homework first.  Find out all you can.  Get familiar with the terminology, technology.  Get your list of questions together, then approach some firms who can provide the service end to end.

It's not difficult to set up a VOIP system and make it work.  But it can be quite difficult to set one up that provides clear voice when you have a loaded internet bandwidth shared by other users data.